# How to get authors name's posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site where users are not logged in and they can post, I am using a plugin called http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/. Their posts are considered as posted by Admin, however, since in the form when they submit they can insert their name, wordpress shows in the admin panel their name.

By doing this i can get a list of the names:

```
<ul>
<?php
 $args= array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
  query_posts($args);
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>     
<li>
    <?php echo get_the_author();  ?>
</li>   
    <?php endwhile; ?> <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

But if I add this:

```
<?php echo get_the_author_posts(); ?>
```

I get a list of the different names but each of them shows me the same number of posts, e.g.:

```
Name1 22
Name2 22
Name3 22
Name4 22
```

This happens because these are not actual users and their are posting on the behalf of the admin.

So how can I get the the link to each post based on the authors names as they display on the admin panel and not by registered users?

Answer (score 0):

The author name is set in a custom field (meta table) named `user_submit_name`, so if you filter the posts by `'meta_key'=>'user_submit_name'` and `'meta_value'=>'John Doe'` then you'll only get posts of that author.

The reason why `get_the_author` returns the correct value is because this plugin hooks into `the_author` and returns the *real* value, from the meta field.

You can query for posts having a certain meta field set to a certain value like this:

```
$my_query  = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_key' => 'user_submit_name',
    'meta_value' => 'John Doe',
    'meta_compare' => '=' 
));
```

Details about WP_Query are [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Don't forget to `wp_reset_postdata` as described there.

Also, as described [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/quick-post-count-using-wp_query-args), you can use `$my_query->found_posts` to get the count.

[This does what you need.](http://pastebin.com/ScNFYRCc)

Comment: that assumes I manually insert 'meta_value', what if I would like to get the meta_value auto?

Comment: `get_the_author` does that already. Just use `'meta_value' => get_the_author()`.

Comment: it's this that doesn't work 'meta_value' => get_the_author(), as I tried with a name and it does find a post

Comment: You are doing this inside the loop, right? (`while...endwhile`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37372/discussion-between-rob-m-and-sergiu-paraschiv)

Answer (score 0):

Bingo!

  ```
   $args= array(
   'posts_per_page' => -1
  );
     query_posts($args);
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>       
  <li>

       <?php
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'meta_key' => 'user_submit_name',
   'meta_value' => get_the_author(),
   'meta_compare' => '='
  );
  $myquery = new WP_Query($args);

  echo '<h3>' . $myquery->found_posts . ' proposte da ' . get_the_author() . '</h3><br>';

  while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) { 
      $myquery->the_post(); 
      echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
  }
  ?>

   <?php   wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  </li>
  ```